# Swagger document link for an API in API Connect

Tags: apiconnect

We should be able to have a link for the swagger document of a published API in API Connect. Currently we are obtaining the swagger from API Connect dev portal. But is there any such link to Swagger document is available in API Connect? We are using API Connect 2018.x

Already mentioned in the problem summary

Answer (score 0):

There are APIs available to retrieve the Open API document for an API. If you want the consumer variant of the document (so it has the right endpoint in it for that catalog's gateway and has had the confidential assembly information redacted out) then you can use the Consumer API.
If you want the provider variant of the document - and so including all the assembly information then you can use the Provider API.

Both APIs are documented here: https://openwhisk.ng.bluemix.net/api/v1/web/API%20Connect%20Native_apic-on-prem/default/index.http

In terms of a link to download it from a UI - I think the consumer variant of the document is only downloadable from the Developer Portal. The provider variant can be downloaded from API Manager UI.